# Datepicker with bootstrap is missing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have one `<input type='date' class='form-control'>` date input for a form. Because I am using form-control from bootstrap 5, the date picker is set as the default white color, the same as the form.

I have searched for multiple ways to change the date picker's color but still nothing.

Code snippet:
https://codepen.io/TCMF/pen/YzLrBYE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
   filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/5/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container form-group col-7">
  <label for>Date: </label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" required  name="date" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the CSS using the `id` or `class` selector.

```css
#date {
  background-color: #abcdef;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/5/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container form-group col-7">
  <label for>Date: </label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" required  name="date" >
</div>
```

Comment: The `id` selector changes the whole input field, is there any selector to change the date picker only?

Comment: You can target the class name that is present on the datepicker

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify more on the date picker's class name? Does the date picker have its own class?